# Split string and put it in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

How to split the string "V237P023F50.5" into different text boxes.

I am trying this code:

```
Dim input As String = "V237P023F50.5"
TextBox1.Text = input

Dim parts As String() = input.Split(New String() {"V"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim parts1 As String() = input.Split(New String() {"V", "P"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim parts2 As String() = input.Split(New String() {"V", "P", "F"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For i As Integer = 0 To parts.Length - 1
    If i > 0 OrElse input.StartsWith("V") = True Then
        parts(i) = "" & parts(i)
        TextBox2.Text = parts(i)
    End If
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To parts1.Length - 1
    If i > 0 OrElse input.StartsWith("P") = True Then
        parts1(i) = "" & parts1(i)
        TextBox4.Text = parts1(i)
    End If
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To parts2.Length - 1
    If i > 0 OrElse input.StartsWith("F") = True Then
        parts2(i) = "" & parts2(i)
        TextBox5.Text = parts2(i)
    End If
Next
```

Expected output

```
V237  
P023   
F50.5
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If this is fixed length then use [Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim oldstring As String = "V237P023F50.5"
TextBox2.Text = oldstring.Substring(0, 4)
TextBox4.Text = oldstring.Substring(4, 4)
TextBox5.Text = oldstring.Substring(8)
```

If the alphacharacters are the same then you can use [IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) with Substring.

```
Dim oldstring As String = "V237P023F50.5"
TextBox2.Text = oldstring.Substring(oldstring.IndexOf("V" ), (oldstring.IndexOf("P") - oldstring.IndexOf("V")))
TextBox4.Text = oldstring.Substring(oldstring.IndexOf("P" ), (oldstring.IndexOf("F") - oldstring.IndexOf("P")))
TextBox5.Text = oldstring.Substring(oldstring.IndexOf("F" ))
```